# Firefox adds an extra "/" for URLS without query parameters

Tags: firefox, macos-mojave

I am using a development server on my local machine with Python/Cherrpy. The page url that I'm trying to load is `localhost:8000/admin`. When I try to load it in Firefox, it redirects me to `localhost:8000/admin/` which breaks the existing rules of url mapping. The same URL loads fine in a private browsing mode and even in Chrome.

I didn't not have this issue until my machine had to restart due to low power. My Firefox version is `70.0.1 (64bit)` and I am on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5.

I tried searching through Bugzilla and even the about:config parameters about this trailing slash appending but no result.

Is anyone else facing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like clearing the history for the site worked. For those who would stumble on this issue in future, open your history sidebar and right click on offending page. You would find an option `Forget About This Site` a.k.a FATS. Click on that and then visit the page again without adding the extra forward slash in URL.